# Parsing all the elements of an xml file

Tags: python, xml

Let's assume I have the following xml file:

```
<test_suite>
<test_case active="0">
    <platform name="octa2">
        <sn>123456</sn>
    </platform>
    <fw_config>octa3</fw_config>
</test_case>
</test_suite>
```

I like to get a dictionary with the all the tags and elements and their values:

```
mydic = {"active":"0","platform_name":"octa2","sn":"123456", "fw_config":"octa3"}
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this in python?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: Yes. I have looked into https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html but have not found a clean way to do it. I can do it by writing a lot of code. But I am assuming there has to be a simple way of doing this. I am looking for some command that gives me all the tags, their corresponding attributes, elements and sub elements and their text at one shot.

Comment: Try using `xml` module. The `etree` function of xml can solve your problem. Please do make sure you have done some research before posting question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving your problem

```
import xmltodict
x = """
    <test_suite>
    <test_case active="0">
        <platform name="octa2">
            <sn>123456</sn>
        </platform>
        <fw_config>octa3</fw_config>
     </test_case>
     </test_suite>
     """
print xmltodict.parse(x)
```

O/P will be a OrderedDict with tags as keys.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> 
>>> root = ET.fromstring('''
... <test_suite>
... <test_case active="0">
...     <platform name="octa2">
...         <sn>123456</sn>
...     </platform>
...     <fw_config>octa3</fw_config>
... </test_case>
... </test_suite>
... ''')
>>> 
>>> [{
...     'active': test_case.get('active'),
...     'platform_name': test_case.find('platform').get('name'),
...     'sn': test_case.find('platform/sn').text,
...     'fw_config': test_case.find('fw_config').text,
... } for test_case in root.iterfind('.//test_case')]
[{'platform_name': 'octa2', 'sn': '123456', 'active': '0', 'fw_config': 'octa3'}]
```